# Why does my node still appear when I set it to null?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm making a BST (Binary Search Tree). I would like some help with my delete method, it seem that when I set that node to null it stills appear when I display it with my display methods (preorder,inorder,postorder).

Here is my node linked list class

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public int value;
    public Node leftValue;
    public Node rightValue;
    public Node(int _value)
    {
        value=_value;
    }
}
```

Here is my delete method in my BST class

```
public void findDelete(Node root, int value)
    {
        if (root== null)
        {
            System.out.println(" Not founded ");
        }
        else if (value < root.value)
        {
            findDelete(root.leftValue,value);
        }
        else if (value > root.value)
        {
            findDelete(root.rightValue,value);
        }
        else if (value == root.value)
        {
            //// checks if have children 
            if (root.leftValue==null&&root.rightValue==null)
            {
                  root = null; 
            }
            //// one
            else if ( root.leftValue==null)
            {
                  root.value=root.rightValue.value;
            }
            else if ( root.rightValue==null)
            {
                root.value=root.leftValue.value;
            }
            //// two
             else if ( root.leftValue!=null && root.rightValue!=null)
            {
                root.value=findMin(root.rightValue);
                findDelete(root.rightValue,value);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(" Not founded ");
        }
    }
```

My delete methods also tries to handle assigning a new successor if the node has children(leafs). May I also get some feedback on if I'm doing it correctly? It tries to handle 3 cases. Case 1 without children, Case 2 1 children, Case 3 2 children.

I think the probably is that the line in my delete method that deletes it by setting it to null if it has no children.

```
if (root.leftValue==null&&root.rightValue==null)
          {
                root = null; 
          }
```

It sets it to null but the root.value still has a int value which makes it still there when I display it with my display method. At least that's what I think the problem is. I would like some help and feedback thanks!

one of my display method

```
public void printPre(Node root)
{
    if (root==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(root.value + ", ");
    printPre(root.leftValue);
    printPre(root.rightValue);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know the difference between objects and references, and between objects and variables?

Comment: I think I do, but if you wouldn't mind clarifying it would be helpful

Comment: do you know the difference between the variable `root`, and the object it refers to?

Comment: The variable `root` in that isn't it passed as a parameter from the main class. So before it could of been like node132 passed into `findDelete(node132,15);`

Comment: Does `Node node132 = new Node(); Node root = node132; root = null; System.out.println(node132);` print null?

Comment: I want to say yes since `Node node132 = new Node()` doesn't have a value, but when you did `Node root = node132` it set `root = node132` which is null then you set `root = null`. Nothing has changed in `node132` beside initializing it so printing it out would be null. At least I think so.

Comment: Different example then. `String string132 = "Hello"; String root = string132; root = null; System.out.println(string132);`

Comment: `String string132 = "Hello"`  `String root = null` 
`System.out.println(string132);` prints out `Hello`,
Yes?

Comment: Yes. What about `public static void delete(String root) {root = null;}` `public static void main(String[] args) {String string132 = "Hello"; delete(string132); System.out.println(string132);}`?

Comment: You declared a `String` to be `string132 = "Hello"` then you passed into the method `delete(string132)` which in that method sets `string132 = null` then when you call `System.out.println(string132)` it prints out `Hello` cause in that method you set `string132 = null` . Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a method, and use variables as arguments, the variables are not passed into the method - only their values. That is why this:

```
class Test1 {
    static void addOne(int i) {
        i++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        addOne(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

prints 5, not 6. To call `addOne`, space for the parameter `i` is allocated, the value 5 is copied from `x` to `i`, the method body runs (setting `i` to 6), and then the method's local variables are destroyed when it returns. `x` is not modified by the call.

Similarly, this:

```
class Test2 {
    static void delete(Node root) {
        root = null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = (something); // not actually (something), but something that returns a Node
        delete(n.leftValue);
    }
}
```

does not modify `n.leftValue`. As before, the local variable `root` is allocated, the value (which is a reference to a `Node` object) is copied from `n.leftValue` to `root`, the method body executes (setting `root` to null) and then the method's local variables are destroyed when it returns. `n.leftValue` is not modified, only `root`.

One alternative is to simply return the new node, since your function currently doesn't return anything. In the above simplified example:

```
class Test3 {
    // returns the new node
    static Node delete(Node root) {
        // in this example it always deletes the node by replacing it with null;
        // obviously your actual code is more complicated than this
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = (something); // not actually (something), but something that returns a Node
        n.leftValue = delete(n.leftValue); // <-- note the change
    }
}
```

Comment: My nodes are declared in a method. How would I find the node to have a null returned to it? In your example for Test3, your Node was declared in the void static main as mine are declared in a method then passed into a method to be inserted in a BST.

Comment: @Dragael instead of `findDelete(root.leftValue, value);` you'd do `root.leftValue = findDelete(root.leftValue, value);`